# sed find string , print everything until next pattern

Tags: sed, greedy

We have the following scenario that we inherited.

*A file with 'hosts per service' is piped into sed.*

*Based on the service name the list of hosts would be returned.*

Command used:

```
/bin/sh -c 'cat file.txt | sed -n "/main-service]/,/\\[/{/\\[/!p;}"'
```

OS(s): Ubuntu 14 16 18 20

On the road we found out that sed is returning more hosts that what we expect.

I'm trying to fix this 'greedy' behavior without modifying the 1st part of the sed ( `'/main-service]/'` ),

A fix for this can be: `'/\[main-service]/'`, but I do not know exactly what it could brake ( this sed is used in a lot of places ), so I'm trying to avoid this edit.

File example ( Sed input ):

```
[main-service]
hosta
hostb
hostc

[that-main-service]
hostd
hoste


[other-main-service]
hostf
hostg
```

In the below example we are looking for all the hosts under the 'main-service'

```
/bin/sh -c 'cat file.txt | sed -n "/main-service]/,/\\[/{/\\[/!p;}"'
```

However, the output is not the one that we expect

```
hosta
hostb
hostc

hostf
hostg
```

I do not know what the creator meant with the sed syntax exactly, but what I'm trying to achieve is:

```
if service name == '/main-service]/' #find only the line that matches

take all the text until '\n\['
```

Example here:

```
https://sed.js.org/?gist=0a90e4d015d02b820072e6cf837e6204
```

Where the expected output is:

```
hosta
hostb
hostc
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: `sed -n '/\[main-service]/{n;:a;p;n;/\[/q;ba}' file` seems to be the solution. You can't use the regex without `\[`, or you will match partially named sections.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples could you please try following in `awk`.

```
awk '/^\[/ && found{exit} /^\[main-service\]/{found=1;next} found && NF' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
hosta
hostb
hostc
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                 ##Starting awk program from here.
/^\[/ && found{       ##Checking condition if line starts from [ and found is NOT NULL then do following.
  exit                ##exit from this program, no need to read whole Input_file.
}
/^\[main-service\]/{  ##Checking condition if line starts from [ main-service] then do following.
  found=1             ##Setting found to 1 here.
  next                ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
found && NF           ##Checking condition if found is SET and NF is NOT NULL then print that line.
' Input_file          ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: thank you for the support but we are trying not to replace sed here, this is where the challenge comes in.

Comment: @CodrinH, oh ok, np I will keep it as an alternative here(in case anyone wants to use it in future), cheers.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n '/\[main-service]/,/^$/{//!p}'
```

would be the best fit, but you mention you are reluctant to use `\[`

so, you can quit on the first such match using

```
sed -n '/main-service]/,/^$/{//!p; /^$/q}'
```

Also, you can directly pass the file name to `sed`, no need to use `cat` and I'm not sure why you are using `/bin/sh -c` instead of calling `sed` directly.

Comment: thank you for the help. I've tried your solution and is still returning the 'hosts' from an upper '*-main-service' for some reason. I tried to replicate this with sed.js.org but the output is not the same as in ubuntu. Regarding the /bin/sh usage, the command is stored into a variable and used by jenkins scripts... I cannot say to much about the design as its quite old..

Comment: I just checked the sed.js.org example (you should have put that full example here as well to avoid confusion)... why should `[that-main-service]` not be matched? on what basis should the program ignore that and match `[main-service]` instead? you are not willing to use `\[` for matching, so unless you tell how to differentiate these two, we cannot help you

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
/bin/sh -c 'cat file | sed -n "/main-service]/{n;:a;p;n;/\\[/q;ba}"'
```

This uses the same regexps but manipulates the program flow.

N.B. The original sed command may have appended more than was intended as the stopping point for the printing depends on another stanza being present or the end of file condition.

Comment: Hi potong, thank you for the response. I've tested your solution and the issue is persisting :( . https://imgur.com/a/111pPTG . Maybe I'm not explaining this correctly ?

Comment: @CodrinH as @Wiktor Stribiżew has pointed out (and you forgot to include in your example) sections above the `[main-service]` which include the string `main-service]` will matched and therefore you must be explicit in naming `[main-service]`

Answer (score 1):

It might help to reconsider the delimiters you have chosen for the range. Because the `]` and `[` brackets are on the same line, the logic is messy.

Use the full pattern of the section header to match the beginning of the range `/^\[main-service]/` and the blank line to match the end of the range `/^$/`

```sh
sed -n  '/^\[main-service]/,/^$/p' services.txt | sed '1d;$d;'
```

- `-n` option to suppress automatic printing.
- `p` command to print the lines of the range

Since the result includes the header and the blank line, we pipe the result into a second command to remove the first and last line `sed '1d;$d;'`